# Discord Bot responding multiple times on an event

Tags: javascript, discord.js, distube

Issue is that bot responds multiple time when a song is added to the queue. When command is ran for the first time, it responds just once and when that event occurs for the second time it will respond twice.

Example:
*play Gabibbo Mashup
Playing: **Gabibbo Mashup**-**00:26**.
On the second time: *play Gabibbo Mashup
Playing: **Gabibbo Mashup** - **00:26**
Playing: **Gabibbo Mashup** - **00:26**)

Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const keepAlive = require('./server.js');
const distube = new DisTube(client, { searchSongs: false, emitNewSongOnly: true })

const prefix = "*"
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log('I am ready')
});

client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift();

    // Queue status template
    const status = (queue) => `Volume: \`${queue.volume}%\` | Filter: \`${queue.filter || "Off"}\` | Loop: \`${queue.repeatMode ? queue.repeatMode == 2 ? "All Queue" : "This Song" : "Off"}\` | Autoplay: \`${queue.autoplay ? "On" : "Off"}\``;

    // DisTube event listeners, more in the documentation page
    distube
        .on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
            `Playing: **${song.name}** - **${song.formattedDuration}**`))
            
        .on("addSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
            `Added **${song.name}** - **${song.formattedDuration}** to the queue by ${song.user}`,
            
        ))
        .on("playList", (message, queue, playlist, song) => message.channel.send(
            `Play **${playlist.name}** playlist (${playlist.songs.length} songs).\nRequested by: ${song.user}\nNow playing **${song.name}** - **${song.formattedDuration}**\n${status(queue)}`
        ))
        
        .on("addList", (message, queue, playlist) => message.channel.send(
            `Added **${playlist.name}** playlist (${playlist.songs.length} songs) to queue\n${status(queue)}`
           
        ))
        
        // DisTubeOptions.searchSongs = true
        .on("searchResult", (message, result) => {
            let i = 0;
            message.channel.send(`**Choose an option from below**\n${result.map(song => `**${++i}**. ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``).join("\n")}\n*Enter anything else or wait 60 seconds to cancel*`);
            
        })
        // DisTubeOptions.searchSongs = true
        .on("searchCancel", (message) => message.channel.send(`Searching canceled`))
        .on("error", (message, e) => {
            console.error(e)
            message.channel.send("An error encountered: " + e);
        });
        if (["p", "play"].includes(command)){
            if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('You must state something to play');
            if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You must be in a voice channel to play music');
            distube.play(message, args.join(" "));
        }
        if (command == 'stop') {
            const bot = message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id);
            if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You must be in a voice channel to stop music');
            if (bot.voice.channel !== message.member.voice.channel) message.channel.send('You must be in the same voice channel as me.');
            distube.stop(message, args.join(" "));
            message.channel.send('I have stopped that song for you')
        }

        if  (["s", "skip"].includes(command)){
            distube.skip(message);
            message.channel.send('I have skipped that song')
        } 
        if (command == 'queque') {
            let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
        message.channel.send('Current queue:\n' + queue.songs.map((song, id) =>
            `**${id + 1}**. **${song.name}** - **${song.formattedDuration}**`
        ).slice(0, 10).join("\n"));
       
        }
         if (["repeat", "loop"].includes(command)) {
        distube.setRepeatMode(message, parseInt(args[0]))
        message.channel.send(`${song.name} is looped`)
        }
        if ([`3d`, `bassboost`, `echo`, `karaoke`, `nightcore`, `vaporwave`].includes(command)) {
            let filter = distube.setFilter(message, command);
            message.channel.send("Current queue filter: " + (filter || "Off"));
        }
});

keepAlive();
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you get a message,  you are adding more event listeners:

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    // other stuff
    distube.on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
        `Playing: **${song.name}** - **${song.formattedDuration}**`
    ));
});
```

Needs to instead be

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    // other stuff
});
distube.on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
    `Playing: **${song.name}** - **${song.formattedDuration}**`
));
```

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const keepAlive = require('./server.js');
const distube = new DisTube(client, { searchSongs: false, emitNewSongOnly: true })

const prefix = "*"
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log('I am ready')
});

client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift();

    // Queue status template
    const status = (queue) => `Volume: \`${queue.volume}%\` | Filter: \`${queue.filter || "Off"}\` | Loop: \`${queue.repeatMode ? queue.repeatMode == 2 ? "All Queue" : "This Song" : "Off"}\` | Autoplay: \`${queue.autoplay ? "On" : "Off"}\``;
    if (["p", "play"].includes(command)){
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('You must state something to play');
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You must be in a voice channel to play music');
        distube.play(message, args.join(" "));
    }
    if (command == 'stop') {
        const bot = message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id);
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You must be in a voice channel to stop music');
        if (bot.voice.channel !== message.member.voice.channel) message.channel.send('You must be in the same voice channel as me.');
        distube.stop(message, args.join(" "));
        message.channel.send('I have stopped that song for you')
    }

    if  (["s", "skip"].includes(command)){
        distube.skip(message);
        message.channel.send('I have skipped that song')
    } 
    if (command == 'queque') {
        let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
    message.channel.send('Current queue:\n' + queue.songs.map((song, id) =>
        `**${id + 1}**. **${song.name}** - **${song.formattedDuration}**`
    ).slice(0, 10).join("\n"));

    }
     if (["repeat", "loop"].includes(command)) {
    distube.setRepeatMode(message, parseInt(args[0]))
    message.channel.send(`${song.name} is looped`)
    }
    if ([`3d`, `bassboost`, `echo`, `karaoke`, `nightcore`, `vaporwave`].includes(command)) {
        let filter = distube.setFilter(message, command);
        message.channel.send("Current queue filter: " + (filter || "Off"));
    }
});

// DisTube event listeners, more in the documentation page
distube
    .on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
        `Playing: **${song.name}** - **${song.formattedDuration}**`))

    .on("addSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
        `Added **${song.name}** - **${song.formattedDuration}** to the queue by ${song.user}`,

    ))
    .on("playList", (message, queue, playlist, song) => message.channel.send(
        `Play **${playlist.name}** playlist (${playlist.songs.length} songs).\nRequested by: ${song.user}\nNow playing **${song.name}** - **${song.formattedDuration}**\n${status(queue)}`
    ))

    .on("addList", (message, queue, playlist) => message.channel.send(
        `Added **${playlist.name}** playlist (${playlist.songs.length} songs) to queue\n${status(queue)}`

    ))

    // DisTubeOptions.searchSongs = true
    .on("searchResult", (message, result) => {
        let i = 0;
        message.channel.send(`**Choose an option from below**\n${result.map(song => `**${++i}**. ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``).join("\n")}\n*Enter anything else or wait 60 seconds to cancel*`);

    })
    // DisTubeOptions.searchSongs = true
    .on("searchCancel", (message) => message.channel.send(`Searching canceled`))
    .on("error", (message, e) => {
        console.error(e)
        message.channel.send("An error encountered: " + e);
    });
keepAlive();
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: if i close the code block at: client.on("message", async (message) => {
    // other stuff
}) the system can't access the command variable

Comment: You don't use `command` in any of your `distube` event handlers from what I can see?

Comment: You are right, but i need to use it after the event handlers, where there actually are commands:` if (["p", "play"].includes(command)){
            if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('You must state something to play');
            if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You must be in a voice channel to play music');
            distube.play(message, args.join(" "));
        }`

Comment: you only need to move the distube event handlers outside, everything else should stay inside.